# How to pass TeamCity parameters to MsBuild?

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild, teamcity, webdeploy

I'm trying to build and deploy ASP.NET web application via TeamCity and WebDeploy. 
Before you ask - I found several similar questions, but neither of them worked in my case. 
I'm trying to pass TeamCity parameters to MsBuild. I have a build template which defines the parameters as empty, and then build configuration override them. 
Tried system properties, but they didn't work for me. What's even worse, TeamCity doesn't log MsBuild parameter values, so I can't take a look at them.
Here's the example of how I pass parameters to MSBuild in my build template: 
`/property:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://$(deploy_vm_name):8172/MsDeploy.axd /property:DeployIisAppPath=$(deploy_app_name) /property:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True /property:UserName=$(deploy_username) 
/property:Password=$(deploy_password)`. 
According to the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+Build+Parameters), syntax is correct. 
Parameters are `system.deploy_app_name, system.deploy_username, system.deploy_password, system.deploy_vm_name`. 
The error message I get - `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4115, 5): Invalid Web Deploy service URL`. 
I'm using TeamCity version 10.0.2 with MsBuild version 14. 
Any suggestions? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

So the correct move was to specify system parameters **named exactly after MSBuild parameters** and then **don't mention those parameters in MSBuild step**. After I did that, all went fine. 
I recognize it's not very flexible solutions since you might have several MSBuild steps, but if anyone knows better one - please share it

Comment: and we've just hit this limitation today *sad panda*

Answer (score 0):

I think because you're defining these properties via arguments in a build step, you need to use the typical %teamcity.parameter% syntax where you are using instead the $(msbuild_parameter) syntax.

Or just skip setting them on the command line entirely. You should be able to resolve the system.parameters from TeamCity in the MSBuild script using the $(msbuild_parameter) syntax.

From the documentation you linked:

> For MSBuild (Visual Studio 2005/2008 Project Files) use $(). Note that MSBuild does not support names with dots ("."), so you need to replace "." with "_" when using the property **inside a build script**.

You aren't inside a build script, you're outside the script defining property arguments.

Comment: you're mostly right, I'll post the working answer with explanations a bit later. thanks